# Cannot import model in templatetags

Tags: python-3.x, django-1.8, wagtail

I am trying to import a Model (that is registered as a snippet) into a templatetags file but it causes the error:

```
'my_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading home.templatetags.my_tags: cannot import name 'NotImportableModel'
```

In my_tags.py I am trying to import the model with:

```
from home.models import NotImportableModel, ImportableModel
```

The interesting part here is that both NotImportableModel and ImportableModel are defined in the same models.py:

```
class ImportableModel(SlugRemoveMixin, Page):
...

@register_snippet
class NotImportableModel(models.Model):
...
```

Could it have something to do with NotImportableModel being a snippet? Or what else could be wrong here? If it is because of the snippet part, what can I do to access the model in my_tags.py?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything relating to snippets that would cause a model to become un-importable. Does `from home.models import NotImportableModel, ImportableModel` work if you run it from the command line (`./manage.py shell`)?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found the problem. It was entirely in my code and not related to snippets. I just found out that both models were actually in a submodels package and the import was still home.models for 'historical' reasons and not correctly updated to home.submodels.